# Gigya - Error 500000 - Could not connect to host

Tags: php, api, gigya

Below is my code:

```
$method  = "accounts.getJWTPublicKey";

$request = new GSRequest($apiKey, $secret, $method, '', true, $userkey);

$request->setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");

$response = $request->send();
```

When it reached the *send function*, the error *500000* is displayed with the message

> Could not connect to host.

Can't really find any solution to this on the internet. Some proposed solution that I have found on gigya was maybe I should:

- Use another Certificate - which can't be the problem because it works on my local and another server on which I was testing.
- A network misconfiguration! Can't find which misconfiguration might have caused this if any.

Had someone been through this and solved this issue?

I am using the PHP SDK given by gigya to communicate with gigya from drupal.

Comment: `eu1.gigya.com` is not opening. so try to provide correct URL

Comment: When using the SDK, it builds a query string using the method and add it to the domain.
And to access 'eu1.gigya.com', you will have to pass the apiKey, secret and userKey which I can't give unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have finally solved the issue. The error was not coming from gigya but from our server. 
It was a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

accounts.getJWTPublicKey is one of Gigya's only publicly accessible APIs. It does not require the same authorization parameters as a secure API. You should be able to access it directly with only the site's API key, like:

```
https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.getJWTPublicKey?apiKey=<API_KEY>
```

I have just confirmed this works on the US Data center, but I don't currently have an EU apikey to check. Let me know if there are still issues accessing the EU data center this way.

[Developer's Guide](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.getJWTPublicKey+REST)

**UPDATED November 19th**

I just had a chance to look at your code and SDK together. If the example you included is the entire request, it is missing the apiKey parameter for the target site. The full request should look like this:

```
$request = new GSRequest($apiKey, $secret, $method, null, true, $userkey);

$request->setAPIDomain("eu1.gigya.com");

$request->setParam("apiKey", "THE_API_KEY_OF_THE_TARGET_SITE"); //This is missing from your example

$response = $request->send();
```

Comment: I added some info to my original answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer  but I am still getting the same error:
`500000 - Could not connect to host`

It works on my local and on another server and without passing the apiKey as a parameter.

I think maybe the error is coming from the server that I am using.

Comment: We tried to reproduce the error a number of ways and were not able to. Ensure that the API key of both sites are correct (no typos) and ensure that the API key you created for your site, is, in fact, configured on the EU data center. If the issue persists, following the above info, please open a support ticket from your Gigya Console.

Comment: All apiKeys are configured on the EU data center. There is the european icon for each one. 
A ticket has already been opened since thursday and they still no answer. 
Thank you for your answers and patience, I'll continue to try to figure out what may be the problem.

Comment: I see that they replied to your ticket and would like some additional information. It appears that Error code 500000 is actually a network error triggered when Gigya's SDK is not able to connect to Gigya's servers. It is not an error triggered from the API. In this case you will need to submit a ping or traceroute to Gigya's server (e.g. https://socialize.eu1.gigya.com). It cannot be troubleshot from our end because the request never reached us. In most cases it is an issue with the external network that is not related to Gigya.